# Users with iOS 11 reporting that navigation bar doesn't change title/buttons when pushing?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I have a navigation controller, and when the root view controller pushes a new view controller onto the stack, the title and bar button items don't update. However this problem doesn't occur anymore when the user reinstalls the app. Is this an iOS 11 bug? What can I do to prevent users from having to reinstall the app?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show the code that you have already tried.